# Why do `quantile` and `fivenum` return different output?

Tags: r

I am slightly confused as to why `quantile` and `fivenum` are returning different output:

```r
quantile(c(1:100, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#>     0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
#>   1.00  25.75  50.50  75.25 100.00
fivenum(c(1:100, NA))
#> [1]   1.0  25.5  50.5  75.5 100.0
```

I checked the description section for the `fivenum` function and found this:

> Returns Tukey's five number summary (minimum, lower-hinge, median, upper-hinge, maximum) for the input data.

Is lower-hinge/upper-hinge different than first-quartile/third-quartile?

Comment: If you check `fivenum`, it is doing `n4 <- floor((n + 3)/2)/2
        d <- c(1, n4, (n + 1)/2, n + 1 - n4, n)
        0.5 * (x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)])`

Comment: `quantile` has different `type` for calculation. `quantile(c(1:100, NA), na.rm = TRUE, type=2)` give the numbers of `fivenum`

Comment: yes, `type = 7` by default, and there are other options from 1 to 9 and type = 2, gets the same output `quantile(c(1:100, NA), na.rm = TRUE, type = 2)
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
  1.0  25.5  50.5  75.5 100.0`  `Type 2- Similar to type 1 but with averaging at discontinuities. γ = 0.5 if g = 0, and 1 otherwise.`